# Adding border subview to UITableViewCell dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a custom bottom border to all of my tableview cells using a UIImageView that I add to the cell programmatically at runtime. The problem is that often as the user scrolls, the border will disappear randomly.

This code is in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
UIImageView* border = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
if (border)
    [border removeFromSuperview];

NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

if (row != sectionRows - 1) {
    UIImageView* border = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[ImageManager sharedManager] imageNamed:@"dashed_border"]];
    [border setFrame:CGRectMake(10, [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath], 290, 1)];
    [border setTag:10];
    [cell addSubview:border];
    [border release];
}
```

It removes a border subview if it exists, and if the row is not a bottom row, it inserts the border at the bottom of the row.

I'm not sure if this is a race condition, or if there are certain times in which cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't called as the user scrolls.

Comment: Does the number of rows in the section ever change?

Comment: And whatever you do, you're better off not always removing the border and re-adding it which seems like it's the most common case. Instead, only remove it if it's there and you are the last row. Normally something as simple as that wouldn't be a big deal, but in table view cells, you don't want to do any work you don't need to.

Comment: No, the number of rows are set according to the number of items in a collection.

Comment: And the border just disappears from random cells and stays gone? I don't see anything obvious ...

Comment: Yep, it's odd. I'll scroll down, then back up and it'll reappear, or disappear from another cell.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cell below is drawn on top of the border. It depends on the order of the subviews in the table view and the order changes as you scroll.

This happens because you are adding the border outside of the cell bounds. Try moving it 1px up. Like:

```
[border setFrame:CGRectMake(10, [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] - 1, 290, 1)];
```